How to determine which executable project uses a given method?
The Facts

I'm using Visual Studio for C# development
We have a large code base – over 650 projects in our Solution
The Solution contains over 50 executable projects
(Obviously, the projects have a complicated hierarchy)

The Problem
The following graph represents my situation. I need to determine which executable project to run and which method from the project has to be called in order for a given method (buried somewhere deep down in the code base) to be called (through a potentially large number of other methods in different projects)
+-------------------+        +-----------------------+        +-------------------+
|                   |        |                       |        |                   |
| ExecutableProject |        | NumerousOtherProjects |        |    SomeProject    |
|                   |        |                       |        |                   |
+-------------------+        +-----------------------+        +-------------------+
|                   |        |                       |        |                   |
| TopLevelMethod() ---- ... ---> SomeOtherMethods() ---- ... ---> TargetMethod()  |
|                   |        |                       |        |                   |
+-------------------+        +-----------------------+        +-------------------+

I need an easy way how to find one or more specimen(s) of ExecutableProject and TopLevelMethod() based on a given TargetMethod()
Of course, the TargetMethod() is known to me, so I could easily display its direct references, however, then I need to repeat the process for all the direct references of these references and so on and so forth, which would be a tedious and unproductive task, not to mention potentially impossible as the TargetMethod() could be easily called through 100 different methods from the TopLevelMethod()
The Question
Is there a nice and easy way how to determine which top-level (executable) projects use a given method through one or more of its methods, either in Visual Studio or using some free tool?

Please could you stop using so much bold? I don't think there's any need for anything in this post to be in bold,  and I don't know about other people, but I certainly find it harder to read posts which have random text in bold.

C# has reflection so potentially ANY code could call your TargetMethod.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/call-hierarchy?view=vs-2022

@JonSkeet I just use the [edit] button... but that's me :).

@HereticMonkey: IMO, that's likely to end up with the OP continuing to post lots of bold that then needs to be cleaned up by other people. Some posters will spot the types of edit applied by others and learn from it, but my experience suggests that's not a very high proportion.

@HereticMonkey: Having said that, I do often just edit to fix indentation, without mentioning it. So I'm definitely inconsistent ;)

@JonSkeet My experience has been about as many people react well to comments as react well to edits, but I'm definitely with you on the overuse of formatting.

@JonSkeet: Are there any guidelines for the formatting? When I look at stackoverflow.com/tour I see that every paragraph has some bold text in order to emphasize its key idea. I try to do the same thing when asking questions. It's surely possible that I overdo it at times. What's the right amount of formatting then?

@Wyck: Calls using reflection wouldn't be visible in the references either. I basically want something which would recursively go through the references so that I don't have to

@Raildex: Thank you, I didn't know about this and it's certainly helpful, however, I still have to go through the references manually

I don't know of any guidelines, but I would say that a tour is at least somewhat different to a question. Aside from anything else, bold seems to be used in the tour page to introduce new terminology/concepts to people... that's not really how you were using it. (I'd personally use less than the tour does - but even so, it's using significantly less proportionally than your original question did.)
